# How do I download the most recent file from FTP using SSIS when the date value has a string data type

Tags: c#, ssis, ftp, script-task

I have files that are named as follows and I want to only select the most recent file for each measure from an FTP site. I don't want to download all of them and delete the ones I don't need.

```
Vendor_Meas1_20170612.txt
Vendor_Meas1_20170613.txt
Vendor_Meas2_20170612.txt
Vendor_Meas2_20170614.txt
Vendor_Meas_3_20170612.txt
Vendor_Meas_3_20170610.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

@Hmen, this is less of an SSIS or FTP question and more of a coding question. One approach would be to use an SSIS script component to write the C# or VB code to  [capture the file names from the ftp site into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1361629/how-do-i-read-the-filenames-inside-the-directory-to-an-array). One of the dimensions reserve for flagging. Iterate through the list--you're looking first for each unique name (the "Vendor_MeasX_" portion of the filename), then [converting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477735/convert-datetime-to-string-formatyyyymmdd) the "yyyymmdd" portion of the file name in the context of a matched "Vendor_MeasX_" group to a date. Place the decided most recent date under the "Vendor_MeasX_" [group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514740/how-to-split-an-array-into-a-group-of-n-elements-each) you are processing into the list. Flag the member in the array. Download the files from the list. Delete the files not flagged in the array. If you prefer, use a dictionary or hashtable as your array.

Comment: Just saw the -1 hit on this. OK, so what approach would be better?